# When does org.hibernate.Session throw HibernateException?

Tags: database, spring, hibernate, orm, hibernate-mapping

I am trying to delete a non existent entity in a database but the delete() method doesn't thow any exception. 
 How can I get an error when I try to delete a non existent entity? 
 I have copied my code below:

```
public void remove(MyEntity persistentInstance) {
 logger.debug("removing entity: " + persistentInstance);
    try {
        sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().delete(persistentInstance);
        logger.debug("remove successful");
    } catch (final RuntimeException re) {
        logger.error("remove failed", re);
        throw re;
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**  
I call the remove in the tests using the following code:

```
final MyEntity instance2 = new MyEntity (Utilities.maxid + 1); //non existent id
    try {
        mydao.remove(instance2);
        sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().flush();
        fail(removeFailed);
    } catch (final RuntimeException ex) {

    }
```

Even if I call a flush the test doesn't fail, why? 
 I would like to get an exception. Anyway I am also interested to understand when the delete() can throw an exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue you are finding is related to the state of the object which you are trying to remove. There are 3 main states used by hibernate: transient, persistent, and detached.

A transient instance is a brand new instance which has never been persisted. Once you persist it, it becomes persistent. After the connection has been closed and the object has been persisted, it is detached. The docs explain in more detail https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en-US/html/objectstate.html#objectstate-overview

Here is an example:

```
MyEntity foo = new MyEntity(); // foo is a transient instance
sessionFactory.getCurrentSession.persist(foo); // foo is now a persisted instance
txn.commit(); // foo is now a detatched instance
```

In your example, you are creating a brand new instance with an unused id, your instance is transient (never been persisted). I think hibernate is ignoring when you call delete for a transient instance. Delete says it removes a persistent instance from the datastore. https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/javadocs/org/hibernate/Session.html#delete(java.lang.Object)

Instead, try something like this:

```
public void remove(long entityId) {
    MyEntity myEntity = myEntityDAO.findById(entityId);
    if (myEntity == null) {
        // error logic here
    } else {
        sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().delete(myEntity);
    }
}
```